# How to use django signals to refresh a specific page

Tags: django

I am creating an ecommerce webapp and I want to update my admin page when user place order. After research i found out about Django signals, but it seems pretty confusing. The idea behind this is that, when a user places an order I want the admin page to be refreshed and show the latest updates. I tried ajax but javascript can only work with the current open page. Can anyone help me with usibg django signals this way?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand a little, if your idea is that the admin page viewed by the user in a browser is to be refreshed. The page viewed by a site visitor is retrieved on demand of the browser. The user could refresh a page, or a page script may auto-refresh on a timer (this is not a very good solution, but it is easy).

Django can't make the browser update the page.

Signals can cause django to do something in the backend, but they can't solve the problem that the browser is in charge.

There is one technology designed to allow the server to push content to the browser: websockets.

If you use websockets (Django's fairly recent built-in support is called Channels (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)), then you can push content to the browser, where a receiving script on the page will do something with it. This is a very powerful technique, but there is a learning curve of some hours if you are starting from scratch.

Recently I came across this front-end library which tries to make this easy as
far as the browser goes: https://htmx.org/docs/

But you still have to deal with running a websocket server and learning how to send messages to a websocket. You will however feel like a superhero at the end of it, so there's that.